# How to verify the time zone change is correct on AWS EC2 using Ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-ec2

We can use the following code to set a new timezone on AWS EC2 using Ansible.

```yaml
---
- hosts: linuxservers proxmoxservers
  remote_user: ansible
  become: yes

  tasks:

  - name: 'Set timezone to Buenos Aires'
    timezone:
      name: America/New_York

  - name: Ansible date fact example
    debug:
      msg="{{ lookup('pipe','date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S') }}"
```

After this,

- How do we verify if the current timezone is set to the expected value?
- How to validate the timezone has been changed correctly (to the desired value)?

Answer (score 1):

**How to validate that ... has been changed correctly (to the desired value)?**

Since Ansible is a Configuration Management Tool with which you set a Desired State, such [validation is part of the modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_checkmode.html) in general.

For [`timezone` module – Configure timezone setting](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/timezone_module.html)

> *It is recommended to restart `crond` after changing the timezone, otherwise the jobs may run at the wrong time.*

After that you may have a look into one the following

> *For Linux it can use `timedatectl` or edit `/etc/sysconfig/clock` or `/etc/timezone` and `hwclock`.*

or better (re-)gather [Ansible Facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts)

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: true
  gather_subset:
    - "!all"
    - "!min"
    - "date_time"

  tasks:

  - name: Show Facts date_time
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_date_time }}"
```

since that will contain the timezone settings or updated timezone settings.

**Further Readings**

Please take note about

- [What is the exact list of Ansible `setup` `min`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71061125/6771046).
- [Using Ansible to verify configurations](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/configuration-verification-ansible)